# How make apache serve static files to django

Tags: django, apache2

I have a django web application running on our **apache2** production server using **mod_python**, but no static files are found (css,images ... )

All our static stuff is under `/var/my.site/example/static`

```
/var/my.site/example/static/
                           |-admin/
                                  |-css/
                                  |-img/     
                           |-css/
                           |-js/
                           |-img/
```

Now I thought I just could alias all requests to my static stuff like so:

This is the apache2 conf:

```
<VirtualHost  123.123.123:443>
    ... SSL stuff ...
    RewriteEngine On    
    ReWriteOptions Inherit 
    <Location "/example">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE example.settings
        PythonPath "[ \
            '/home/me/Envs/ex/lib/python2.6/site-packages',\
            '/var/my.site',\
            '/home/me/Envs/ex/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django',\
            '/home/me/Envs/ex/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb',\
            '/var/my.site/example',\
            '/var/my.site/example/static'] + sys.path"
        PythonDebug Off

    </Location>

    Alias /example/static /var/my.site/example/static    
    <Directory /var/my.site/example/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This is my settings.py

```
...
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/my.site'
STATIC_URL = '/example/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/var/my.site/example/static",
)
...
```

There is no errors in the apache-error log. But here log from apache-secure_access.log

```
[09/Aug/2012:12:37:55 +0200] "GET /example/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6694
[09/Aug/2012:12:37:55 +0200] "GET /example/static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 301 468
[09/Aug/2012:12:37:55 +0200] "GET /example/static/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 403 766
[09/Aug/2012:12:37:55 +0200] "GET /example/static/css/base.css/ HTTP/1.1" 500 756
[09/Aug/2012:12:37:55 +0200] "GET /example/static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 301 622
```

But this doesn't work and I'm not sure, if I even, is on the right track. It does work when I set `DEBUG = True` But that's just because django serves all the static files.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**Does anyone know about a good tutorial or example?**

Comment: does putting Alias /example/static /var/my.site/example/static    
before <Location "/example"> make a difference?

Comment: can you show ... django-stuff ...?

Comment: Thanks for taken your time to look at it! I've updated the question with my django-stuff

Comment: Try making it <Directory "/var/my.site/example/static">

Comment: @Keegen Thanks for the suggestion, but no that didn't help either ...

Comment: I know you said you're using mod_python, but I use mod_wsgi to do exactly what you're talking about. Here's the documentation that got me going: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#Hosting%5FOf%5FStatic%5FFiles

Comment: @themanatuf Thanks it is a good doc, but I've already looked at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After @supervacuo suggestion that I strip down everything from django, I got apache to serve the static files and realized what was wrong.

The problem was that `<Location "/example">` got priority over `Alias /example/static`. It didn't matter where I put the `Alias` (above or below the `<Location> - tag`).

To fix it I changed the `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`, than I could change the `Alias` not to interfere with the  `<Location> - tag`

**From:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/my.site'
STATIC_URL = '/example/static/'

Alias /example/static /var/my.site/example/static
```

**To:**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/my.site/example'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Alias /static /var/my.site/example/static
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to eliminate the problem step-by-step.

Loading static files should work completely independently of Django. Try commenting out all lines relating to Django in your `VirtualHost` config. (Remember to reload Apache after changing the configuration)

If that works, it may be that you need to take more steps to avoid Django trampling over URLs in the same namespace (perhaps using `SetHandler`?).

If not, there's a more basic problem with your static files. If you can't resolve it, perhaps [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) can help?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see is with this:

`"GET /example/static/css/base.css/ HTTP/1.1" 500 756`

Since `/base.css/` is not a valid link; it gets passed to django; and since it doesn't match a URL pattern it raises a 500. You should fix the template that has the errant `/`.

Comment: Actually, this is related to the `301` a couple of lines above it; it's [Django's `APPEND_SLASH` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#append-slash) kicking in.